# redimensionar imagem "a dedo" em pagina web

Tags: jquery, html5, imagem, plugin, redimensionamento

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma técnica, um plugin, seja o que for, algo que  permita redimensionar uma imagem que esteja na minha pagina da web de maneira interativa com o usuario, como o que a imagem a seguir mostra:[image: exemplo]

Comment: Sempre uso e talvez possa te ajudar: http://rafaelcouto.com.br/redimensionar-imagem-antes-de-enviar-com-javascript/

Comment: não é esse tipo de redimensionamento estatico q quero @GuilhermeGouveiaAlves, o que quero é redimensionar a imagem com o tamanho que eu quiser, como se fosse no word, entende?

Comment: O [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) resolve seu problema?